# How to set scope for i18n URLs in a pwa?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, angular-i18n

I have a progressive web-app : [Click here](https://api-project-456878020393.firebaseapp.com/fr/)

As you can see, at the end of the domain, there is a /language. My PWA is accessible for /en too as it is completely i18n compatible.

My problem is that when I try to set it up on the desktop it still points to '/' and it cannot find any index.html. The language path is not taken into account it seems.
Part of my manifest.json is:

```
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "./*",
  "start_url": "/",
```

I have tried setting the scope like this because setting it to "." does not work.
Now the message is:
**Property 'scope' ignored. Start url should be within scope of scope URL.**

Other point: it is deployed to firebase.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your "Click here" link can't be accessed without logging in.

Comment: Hello. There is no point to connect as my question is domain and deployment related. All you have to look at is the URL.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Maybe the following post could solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69492759/17097243